# I want to improve, but the question is impossible to salvage, what do I do?

Tags: support

I no longer work with Objective-C (Not that I ever knew what I really was doing) and I have some pretty bad questions (Some I deleted) and I am unsure what to do. They are in an area I have no knowledge about, and something I will never know about.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697809/cocos2d-and-gamekit for instance was one, and it was a duplicate of the same question I asked (I basically tried moving it to the top) which again was written poorly, and again is practically unsalvageable. I can barely tell where I was trying to go with it, as it basically makes no sense.

What should I do to improve the terrible questions I know nothing about? (I have a question ban as a result of these bad questions and would like to be unbanned so I may ask actual questions) Side note: I know there are similar questions but my circumstances are a bit different as I have very few questions and don't feel that the answers adequately apply to me.

Answer (score 18):

We're working on improving our question block mechanism to give folks that *can* be helped a better chance of getting better. Just *being* on Stack Overflow and reading the better questions and answers can go a long way toward teaching folks how to effectively communicate their problems and ideas, but that takes *time*.

When you feel as if you've gotten to the point that you *could* ask good questions but can't because a bunch of unsalvageable crap is weighing you down, [get in touch with us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and explain your situation - we'll see what we can do to help you *if* you can show us that you *can* be helped.

In your case, you don't appear to be blocked any longer, so I suspect you were simply right on the edge. Just treat your questions as a consumable resource that *can* be depleted if over-used, which means asking them only when you really need to, and making them count when you do.

#### Now, a more general note:

Contacting us with something like:

> i can no longer ask questions plz enable my acct.

Which we see 20 - 30x *daily*, will probably just get you ignored. This means you've moved on to wasting *our* time, which is something we don't like to do. If you contact us about a block, you need to make sure you *strongly* indicate that you've read the advice you were given (by clicking the link) and made some effort to improve your posts. *Contacting us otherwise will not help you at all*.

Comment: I would like to add that maybe before allowing users to post questions for the first time, they be required to read a lesson/read an article and then take a small quiz of sorts to show that they actually know how to correctly ask a question and participate in the community.

Answer (score 2):

That's a good thing you want to do to improve.

Why do you think your situation is different from the ones mentioned in the other meta Q/A's?

Have you read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) one?

I'm highlighting a part of it here for you:

> ***How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?***
>
> Automatic bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot
>   simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action,
>   you will never be allowed to post again. The only way for the ban to
>   be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways.
>
> Moderators cannot lift the ban.
>
> *Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts! As noted above,
>   down-votes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so
>   the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any
>   objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did
>   they fail to show any effort on your part? Poorly worded, titled,
>   formatted, and overly long or short? Then fix them!*
>
> Note the emphasis on fixing. Do not delete your posts. As explained
>   above, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) do
>   still count towards the question ban. Deleting your posts does not
>   help to lift the ban. Only fixing does! Under some conditions you can
>   see a list of your own deleted questions and answers.
>
> *If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality
>   answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again. But
>   as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for
>   sure.*
>
> If you really, really think the ban is an error, then email the team
>   directly using the "contact us" link provided at the bottom of every
>   page. But note that reactivation of banned accounts is not a high
>   priority.

So, the answer is, edit your previous posts, add further details to them, show us what you've tried, or if you've found a solution, provide the answer to your own question.

And the other answer is, contribute! Check others' questions and answer them if you know the answer and provide a good quality, helpful answer.

Comment: Again, I have very few posts, 5 in total, all of which I am unable to revise in a way that would provide any positive contribution.

Comment: Hmm... Are you able to answer questions?

Comment: Yeah, I am, I did that the first time to get unbanned, but then I wrote a bad question, which I realized, then deleted. Which was a big mistake as I got banned pretty much right after. Looking back, it's no wonder I got banned with all these terrible questions.

Comment: Ok @BrandonGelfand. Try checking the new questions in your field of expertise, and provide good-quality, helpful answers. I am sure there are questions that you can answer. Be active, and contribute, as you get a better reputation, you'll gain more privileges and will be able to contribute even more, in addition to being unbanned from asking questions.

As I read the help and the guidelines, there's no other way of being unbanned from asking questions with waiting or asking moderators, etc.