# Should I fix a question that was based on silly, but not a typo, mistake?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777707/painting-on-a-widget-that-contains-a-qgridlayout-in-pyside-pyqt) that was based on a mistake that, if I had more deliberately considered the tools I was using, I would not have made.

I'm of two minds about what to do with this question. One, flag it for removal because it is based on a silly mistake (though not a typo). Or, two, because someone else may make the same silly mistake, rewrite the question for that future mistake-maker (i.e., change the title, and content, in light of the solution).

Which of my minds is right? I have already made the edits, hopefully improving its potential to help someone, so am leaning toward not requesting a delete. However, it is still far from a stellar question.

**Related post**

[I want to improve, but the question is impossible to salvage, what do I do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260867/i-want-to-improve-but-the-question-is-impossible-to-salvage-what-do-i-do)

Comment: A Mars lander was lost because of a mistake comparable to that, so it's hardly "silly". I'm not sure anything needs to be done to the question. The question demonstrates a problem, the answer shows what you did wrong.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, though you are probably seeing the edited version. The first version it was a lot less clear, as I didn't yet know the answer. :)

Comment: Your edit could just as well have been a comment on the answer. Something like "Oh, silly me, I was thinking of grid coordinates instead of point coordinates."